# Create Network Tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv4, wireguard, gre

Currently, I host a server in my house and a VPS from OVH. Is there a way I could create a network tunnel that lets me use any extra IP addresses from the OVH VPS for the server I have at home?

If there's a way I can assign the IP addresses to a router at my house, then use it for my servers. That would be ideal as well.

I've tried this using GRE and Wireguard but none of them were able to let me create VPS's using KVM or dockers on them. What's the best way to do this?

(This way I get cheaper IPv4 addresses since my ISP charges quite a bit for them and I get cheap DDOS protection).

My use for this is to host game servers and create VPS's for other uses. I want the IP addresses to work exactly how it would work if it's assigned by a router.